# Projections on different fields depending on object class

Tags: querydsl

I have an abstract class A and class B which extends class A.

I want to do projections which will be dependent on real object class.

Is it possible to do in querydsl (v 3.7.2) something like this :

```
new CaseBuilder()
.when(qObject.innstaceOf(B.class))
.then(qObject.as(B.class).fieldFromBclass)
.otherwise(qObject.field.fieldFromAclass)
```

So is it possible to do projection on different fields, depending on object type?

Answer (score 0):

querydsl Q classes are auto-generated classes that map database tables into Java representations (`RelationalPathBase`) of the class, so that they can be queried like a database table with the added benefit of using querydsl's fluent API / compile-time type safety etc.

I guess from the example that there is an `abstract class A` and `class B extends A` and that these are POJOs designed to collect the results of the SQL statement into a `Collection` of Java Objects. Ultimately I think you want a `List` of Java objects where each object has all the fields returned from the `SELECT` statement.

Looking at the `CaseBuilder` in the example, all querydsl is doing here is converting the Java syntax into SQL and running it on the database over JDBC. The database doesn't know about the Java. E.G. this would be a standard use of a `CaseBuilder`.

```
new CaseBuilder()
.when(qObject.name.eq("Robert Bain"))
.then("Rob")
.otherwise("Not Rob")
```

This would generate the SQL (Oracle syntax)

```
CASE WHEN q_object.name = 'Robert Bain' THEN 'Rob' ELSE 'Not Rob' END
```

We can't know what the database is going to return until after the statement has been executed, so there's no way of knowing what POJO class to populate. I also don't see why it's useful, since the SQL statement will return the same columns of the same types and so can populate the same class. Why differentiate?

If there is a need to differentiate, my advice would be to have one class you use to project into (or use `Tuple`) and perform the logic to separate the rows into different classes in the service layer, after the data has been returned.